# Linux user permissions for Magento PHP apache developer

Tags: php, linux, apache, magento, amazon-ec2

I am hiring a developer to install and configure Magento 2.0 on my **Amazon EC2 Linux** server.  I am new to Linux and Magento.  I have given them SSH access and created a [magento file system owner](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html) user.  They can login to the server with SSH keys but they are saying they don't have `sudo` or `sudo su` privileges. I added them to the `wheel` group the following line is in the `sudoers` file

```
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I need some guidance on what to do.  I want them to  be able to do everything they need to install and configure Magento which is a PHP application running on Apache.

Should just give them root access?

This is what happens when they try to restart apache

```
[magentodev1@ip-172-131-157-14 ~]$ service httpd restart
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied [FAILED]
rm: cannot remove '/var/lock/subsys/httpd': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid 
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.  [FAILED]
[magentodev1@ip-172-131-157-14 ~]$ sudo service httpd restart
[sudo] password for magentodev1:
Sorry, try again.
```

Comment: (A) How much do you trust your developer, (B) how much sensitive data is available if you did give him access to that server?

Comment: @RobbieAverill A-it's the first time I've hired them but they have good reviews.  B-It's a blank server besides the PHP and apache installation.  It will become the production server after development is complete.  It is easiest just to give them root access so they can do what they need?

Comment: Sounds safe then. Any SSH access from that server to others in your VPC?

Comment: I would highly discourage giving them root access. Did they open a new session? Group changes aren't going to be put into effect until existing sessions are exited and a new one is made. You could reboot to be sure.

Comment: @RobbieAverill No, just MySQL access to a RDS MySQL server.  So what are you suggesting?  That I give them root access?  The steps I did above didn't work, they say they can't use `sudo su`.

Comment: Or you could have them do a `newgrp wheel` and you wouldn't have to reboot or logout.

Comment: You could always perform the tasks required by a root user for them yourself. It should only be setting file and directory permissions or setting up the Magento cron. Probably installing Magerun and maybe another tool or two. Nothing else required to make Magento work. If you give root access and you have other data on the RDS server then that's a potential risk, however I imagine that the user you've created for them would also have access to the RDS instance anyway...

Comment: @vesche  They are in the wheel group but they still can't do things like `service httpd restart`

Comment: Since you hired them, anytime they need root access for a task you could perform that piece yourself, or type in the password yourself. If you find out exactly what they need root access for (or sudo), you could limit it to just those commands and tasks for a temporary period (2 hours, etc)

Comment: @Heinrich Right, but after you add them to the wheel group you need to close pre-existing sessions. They will be in the wheel group, but it won't take effect until those sessions are closed. You should reboot or have them run `newgrp wheel` in the their session.

Comment: @vesche I closed session and ran `newgrp wheel`, they still can't restart apache or `sudo su`

Comment: @Heinrich Hm, maybe just add them to the sudo group? `sudo adduser magentodev1 sudo`

Comment: Based on the error you posted now, it looks like they aren't putting the password in correctly or else you would get a permission error instead of `Sorry, try again.`

Comment: @vesche  What will adding to sudo group allow them to do?  Anything root can do?  Or is it more restricted?

Comment: It will allow them sudo access, which means anything that root can do- but they will have to confirm their password.